# ViewPager "TransactionTooLargeException" on test ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I'm implementing ViewPager for the first time and I'm facing some issue because I get following error:

```
06-20 10:40:51.366 11377-11377/com.example.ruelas.elite E/AndroidRuntime: Error reporting crash
                                                                      android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: data parcel size 26485896 bytes
                                                                          at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
                                                                          at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:503)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.handleApplicationCrash(ActivityManagerNative.java:4425)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$UncaughtHandler.uncaughtException(RuntimeInit.java:90)
                                                                          at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:693)
                                                                          at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:690)
```

Im not doing anything fancy with ViewPager but I'm not able to make it work, this is the Activity thats running it:

```
package com.example.ruelas.elite;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class setup extends AppCompatActivity {
ViewPager vpSetup;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_setup);
    vpSetup = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.vpSetup);
    vpSetup.setAdapter(new adapterSetup(getSupportFragmentManager()));
}
}
```

The adapterSetup Class:

```
package com.example.ruelas.elite;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.util.Log;

public class adapterSetup extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
String [] titulos = new String[]{"Modalidad", "Temas"};
public adapterSetup(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    switch (position){
        case 0:
            Log.d("case0","case0");
            return new fragmentModalidad();
        case 1:
            return new fragmentTemas();
        default:
            return null;
    }
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return titulos.length;
}
@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return titulos[position];
}
}
```

My gradle since I think it may have something to do with this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.ruelas.elite"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.0'
}
```

One of the fragments (they are just XMLS with a Large Text in them:

```
package com.example.ruelas.elite;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

/**
 * Created by Ruelas on 20/06/2016.
 */
public class fragmentModalidad extends Fragment{
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmentmodalidad, container, false);
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance, feel free to ask if I missed any necessary information.

Answer (score 8):

My bad guys, the other class inflater was not calling the correct constructor, it was:

```
return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmentmodalidad, container);
```

When:

`return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmentmodalidad, container, false);`

was needed

Comment: U saved me :) Thanks a lot, Can u also tell me what exact difference in those both situations? that made this exception

Comment: The last parameter refers to whether or not you would like to add the child to the GroupView in the second parameter (in that precise moment), in this case, you don't want to add it (and also you can't) , you just want to return a GroupView resulting from inflating the resource. Hence trying to add the inflated resource to the "container" parameter will result on the error we have just seen.